# BufferedReader is skipping every other line when reading my file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, lines

So Im working of reading a file containing appointments that I wrote to earlier in my code. I want to sift through the text file and find appointments on a certain date and add them to an ArrayList but when the BufferedReader goes through it, it skips ever other line... Heres my code

```
public ArrayList<String> read(int checkDay, int checkMonth, int checkYear) {
    ArrayList<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String read;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("calendar.txt"));
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            read = in.readLine();

            String[] split = read.split(",");
            System.out.println(read);

            if (split[1].equals(Integer.toString(checkDay)) && split[2].equals(Integer.toString(checkMonth)) && split[3].equals(Integer.toString(checkYear))) {
                events.add(split[0] + " : " + split[1] + "/" + split[2] + "/" + split[3]);
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    return events;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You are reading the line twice..

```
while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) { // here
            read = in.readLine();      // and here
```

Answer (score 3):

You have error here:

```
while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) 
 read = in.readLine();
```

you should keep the read = in.readLine() in the while. and remove the other line.

Answer (score 1):

pl try this

you r using "read = in.readLine())" two times in while loop that why it is skiping the lomes

```
public ArrayList<String> read(int checkDay, int checkMonth, int checkYear) {
        ArrayList<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String read;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("calendar.txt"));
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] split = read.split(",");
                System.out.println(read);

                if (split[0].equals(Integer.toString(checkDay)) && split[1].equals(Integer.toString(checkMonth)) && split[2].equals(Integer.toString(checkYear))) {
                    events.add(split[0] + " : " + split[1] + "/" + split[2] + "/" + split[3]);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
        return events;
```

Comment: Where is the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

may be usage of "next()" over "nextLine()" should resolve the issue:

```
System.out.println("Enter Emp ID: ");
        eid = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Emp Name:");
        ename = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Emp Salary:");
        esal = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter Emp Address:");
        eaddr = scanner.next();
```